# Error when running react native app in OS X mojave - SHA-1 for file ...node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js is not computed

Tags: react-native

I am getting the following error when running a react native app:

```
SHA-1 for file .../node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js is not computed
```

I already researched several forums, several posts from here, but none solved my problem.
All packages are up to date.
And this application runs on windows and linux.
Anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2743

Comment: Curiously I had already gone through this link, but had not tried to delete the `.watchmanconfig` file.
I deleted it and the application finally ran! Thanks.